# How to alphabetize selected content in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, alphabetical-sort

I am trying to take the content that I add to and alphabetically group into lists that have a 'header' for each letter. So in other words, I want to highlight the desired content in my blog editor, and then automatically alphabetize and format that content into something like this:

[image]

Seems like it could be done with some healthy sized custom PHP scripts or maybe some equally tedious javascript or jquery? Any suggestions on plugins or methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how performant this is, but here's a basic implementation that does it purely in php.

Basically within the post loop (that you orderby 'title', ascending) you check if the first letter is the same as the previous title's first letter. If it is, don't do anything special. If it is different, then that means it's the end of that letter so end the list, post the new letter's title and then continue through the loop.

```
<?php 
// Get posts in alphabetical order
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );

    $allposts = get_posts( $args ); 
?>

<ul>
<?php 
        $previous = 0;
        $current = 1;
?>

<?php foreach($allposts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post); 

        // Grab the first letter of the post
        $current = substr(the_title('', '', false), 0, 1);

        // Is it the same as the section we're in?
        if ($previous != $current) {
            // If it's not the same, break the list, and start a new section
            ?>
            </ul>
            <h2><?php echo $current; ?></h2>

            <?php $previous = $current; ?>
            <ul>
        <?php } ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is awesome, and I found plenty of plugins that do this, but I'm trying to implement this same thing to my content. AKA text I enter in the editor to be printed in $the_content();